# Extract relationship concepts from sentences

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, information-extraction, relation-extraction

Is there a current model or how could I train a model that takes a sentence involving two subjects like:

> [Meiosis] is a type of [cell division]...

and decides if one is the child or parent concept of the other? In this case, cell division is the parent of meiosis.

Answer (score 2):

Are the subjects already identified, i.e., do you know beforehand for each sentence which words or sequence of words represent the subjects? If you do I think what you are looking for is relationship extraction.

## Unsupervised approach

A simple unsupervised approach is to look for patterns using part-of-speech tags, e.g.:

First you tokenize and get the PoS-tags for each sentence:

```
sentence = "Meiosis is a type of cell division."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize("Meiosis is a type of cell division.")
tokens
['Meiosis', 'is', 'a', 'type', 'of', 'cell', 'division', '.']

token_pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
token_pos
[('Meiosis', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('type', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'),
 ('cell', 'NN'), ('division', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

Then you build a parser, to parse a specific pattern based on PoS-tags, which is a pattern that mediates relationships between two subjects/entities/nouns:

```
verb = "<VB|VBD|VBG|VBN|VBP|VBZ>*<RB|RBR|RBS>*"
word = "<NN|NNS|NNP|NNPS|JJ|JJR|JJS|RB|WP>"
preposition = "<IN>"
rel_pattern = "({}|{}{}|{}{}*{})+ ".format(verb, verb, preposition, verb, word, preposition)
grammar_long = '''REL_PHRASE: {%s}''' % rel_pattern
reverb_pattern = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar_long)
```

NOTE: This pattern is based on this paper: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D11-1142

You can then apply the parser to all the tokens/PoS-tags except the ones which are part of the subjects/entities:

```
reverb_pattern.parse(token_pos[1:5])
Tree('S', [Tree('REL_PHRASE', [('is', 'VBZ')]), ('a', 'DT'), ('type', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')])
```

If the the parser outputs a REL_PHRASE than there is a relationships between the two subjects. You then need to analyse all these patterns and decide which represent a `parent-of` relationships. One way to achieve that is by clustering them, for instance.

## Supervised approach

If your sentences already are tagged with subjects/entities and with the type of relationships, i.e., a supervised scenario than you can build a model where the features can be the words between the two subjects/entities and the type of relationship the label.

```
sent: "[Meiosis] is a type of [cell division.]"
label: parent of
```

You can build a vector representation of `is a type of`, and train a classifier to predict the label `parent of`. You will need many examples for this, it also depends on how many different classes/labels you have.

Comment: Thanks! For the supervised approach, what word embedding do you recommend I use for clustering?

Comment: You can simple add the word embeddings of each word, maybe removing adjectives/stopwords; I wouldn't favour any particular embeddings method, more important is the domain, if possible train embeddings on the domain of your data.

Comment: Ok, and for the unsupervised approach, once I have the patterns how do I cluster them? Do I need a word embedding too?

Comment: embeddings are just a representation, you can use whatever you want, one-hot encoding TF-IDF weighted, sum embeddings of the words; i.e. you need to come up with a vector representation and then you apply a clustering algorithm